# Editing an enum in a class (member cannot be accessed with an instance reference)

Tags: c#, class, enums

I'm trying to edit an enum value in a class instance based on whether that instance appears in a dictionary of type `<string, myClass>`. What seems logical to me is to do the code snippets below:

```
if (pumpDict.ContainsKey(ID))
                {
                    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, PumpItem> kvp in pumpDict)
                    {
                        if(kvp.Key == ID)
                        {
                            kvp.Value.state = kvp.Value.state.Available; //error here
                            kvp.Value.fuelPumped = fuelPumped;
                            kvp.Value.fuelCost = fuelCost;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    PumpItem pump = new PumpItem();
                    pumpDict.Add(ID, pump);
                }
```

And my PumpItems class is such:

```
namespace PoSClientWPF
{
    public enum pumpState
    {
        Available,
        customerWaiting,
        Pumping,
        customerPaying
    };

    public enum fuelSelection
    {
        Petrol,
        Diesel,
        LPG,
        Hydrogen,
        None

    };
    class PumpItem
    {   
        public double fuelPumped;
        public double fuelCost;

        public fuelSelection selection;
        public pumpState state;    

        public PumpItem()//intialize constructor
        {                
            this.fuelPumped = 0;
            this.fuelCost = 0;
            this.selection = fuelSelection.None;
            this.state = pumpState.Available;

        }

    }
}
```

I was led to believe that to have an enum value in a constructor, they have to be set up as above, with a new instance of those enums declared in the class body.

It seems to me, that what I'm trying to do is logical but I am getting an error on the right hand side of the assignation which states:

"member PoSClientWPF.pumpState.Available cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify is with a type name instead"

I've searched for this error among several forums but only seem to find errors involving calling static variables incorrectly. Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `kvp.Value.state.Available;` for `pumpState.Available;`

Comment: `kvp.Value.state = pumpState.Available`?

Comment: both indeed correct, don't know why I didn't spot the incorrect assignation myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly accessing the `Enum` member:

```
// this is incorrect
kvp.Value.state = kvp.Value.state.Available; //error here

// this is the correct way
kvp.Value.state = PoSClientWPF.pumpState.Available;
```

Answer (score 0):

You know you have a dictionary?

```
PumpItem pumpItem = pumpDict[ID];
pumpItem.state = PoSClientWPF.pumpState.Available;
```

or

```
PumpItem pumpItem;
if (pumpDict.TryGetValue(ID, out pumpItem))
{
    pumpItem.state = PoSClientWPF.pumpState.Available;
}
else
{
    pumpItem = new PumpItem();
    pumpDict.Add(ID, pumpItem);
}
```

Could just add ID to PumpItem and use a List

```
PumpItem pumpItem = pumpList.FirstOrDefualt(x => x.ID == ID)
if (pumpItem == null)
    pumpList.Add(new PumpItem(ID));  
else
    pumpItem.state = PoSClientWPF.pumpState.Available;

class PumpItem
{
    public double fuelPumped = 0;
    public double fuelCost = 0;
    public fuelSelection selection = fuelSelection.None;
    public pumpState state = pumpState.Available;
    public Int32? ID = null; 

    public PumpItem()//intialize constructor
    { }
    public PumpItem(Int32? ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```